# ELK Stack and Redis. Can I stop the DB being emptied?

Tags: redis, elastic-stack

I have a running live system that uses a redis DB and an old ELK stack. I am creating a new version. What I want is to use the input section of my new Logstash to read the data from the old redis DB, but in my tests when I do this I seem to drain the data from it. I do not want to modify in anyway the current logstash or live pipeline implementation (i.e. add a 2nd output to the live logstash config).

```
LIVE Data -> Redis -> Logstash -> ES -> Kibana
               |                          :
            Read only               compare old with new
               |                          :       
               V                          V
            New Logstash -> New ES -> New Kibana
```

I feel I am missing something about the relationship between logstash and redis. I was hoping to simply duplicate the redis read in my new logstash config and validate that the pipeline behaves the same as the old one before I go live with it, but if I am deleting this data rather than duplicating it I'm going to seriously upset the monitoring team!

How can I prevent my new logstash from draining the logs from redis?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without answering this question. I used a [redis replica](https://redis.io/topics/replication) e.g.

```
LIVE Data -> Redis    ->    Logstash    ->    ES    -> Kibana
               |                                          :
            Read only                                  compare
               |                                          :       
               V                                          V
           Redis Replica -> New Logstash -> New ES -> New Kibana
```

The only issue was the data was pulled out so quickly from the old Redis DB by logstash that I was unable to read it with the new logstash (usually, bits got through). The DB sent an LPOP to the replica and the data removed. This was not too bad as I could then stop the logstash on the old system, let the new system fill it's ES database, then re-enable the old logstash, which would catch up very quickly. They then had the same set of data for the same period and I could compare.

Have not worked out a way to run these 2 systems at the same time but this is good enough for my purposes as it does not change the config of the old system, just interrupt it for a while.